# What causes: Error -135: socket write error

Tags: ftp

I am trying to upload a 12MB .wav file on a Mac running Transmit to a Linux box running Apache and get the following error after uploading just 160KB of the file:

error-135-socket-write-error

Any clues why I may be getting this? I have successfully uploaded much larger files in the past and nothing has changed on the configuration.

Comment: I edited the question. You can take away the -1 now.

Comment: I still don't see anything programming-related in the question.

Comment: I vote we close it. I added it to superuser. Thanks.

Comment: Questions are automatically migrated to other sites when they get enough appropriate close votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disk was full and this caused the error -135.

Answer (score 1):

Check the File Name are there spaces or symbles in it

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing which OS is running on the client and the server (i.e. where the error code might come from). The error means that the client couldn't send any more data to the server. This is either because the server stops accepting more bytes (hangup, disk full, quota exceeded) or because the connection times out (but then, I'd expect a "connection reset by peer" error).